# Wordpress sub-posts and permalinks

Tags: posts, permalinks, parent-theme

I'm thinking about one problem... There is a set of regular posts. Just posts in categories. 
I need to add for some of them a sort of subposts, posts which will be related to parent-post.

This issue can be solved by adding meta_box to edit post page. (any better ideas?)

Another problem is about permalink of this sub-post.
If parent-post have permalink like this http://blabla.com/simple-post/ then i need sub-post with permalink like this http://blabla.com/simple-post/little-sub-post/
How can i deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Pages work this way, so you could either use pages or [create a new post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) (you'd need the `hierarchical => true`:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name', 'your_text_domain'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name', 'your_text_domain'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book', 'your_text_domain'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book', 'your_text_domain'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Book', 'your_text_domain'),
    'new_item' => __('New Book', 'your_text_domain'),
    'all_items' => __('All Books', 'your_text_domain'),
    'view_item' => __('View Book', 'your_text_domain'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Books', 'your_text_domain'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No books found', 'your_text_domain'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash', 'your_text_domain'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Books', 'your_text_domain')

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => _x( 'book', 'URL slug', 'your_text_domain' ) ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 
  register_post_type('book', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. What if i want to "add" book to regular post as a child? How can i do this in terms of admin interface?